# How can I add a margin to all pages of a PDF document?

Tags: mac, pdf

For a purpose of putting further annotations on PDF, I need to increase the right margin of all pages in a PDF. The page size does not have to stay the same, it is alright if it changes because of the margin change. The content of the PDF should not move, I just want to extend the right margin further to the right.

I found an [online service](https://deftpdf.com/resize-pdf) but I need to apply this margin change in batch and would like to avoid payment.
I am using MacBook Air M1 with Monterey installed.

How can I change the right margin of all pages of a PDF document using a free tool?

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF in Preview and printing to PDF from there while setting the margins as desired? [This Apple.SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/112546/24324) explains how to set those margins.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I have tried it actually but after I readjusted the custom paper size (if I do not readjust, the Preview showed error and return the margin number to its origin), it affected the content of the PDF though i.e. if I change to 20 x 20 inches of paper size, the PDF is cropped by height. If I change to 40 x 20 inches, I have to scroll very hard with my mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after trying out different page configurations I think I figured out the trick.

I assume you want to add a margin of `100 mm` on the right of each page, but feel free to choose any value that you want. I also assume that your document originally has A4 pages of `210 x 297 mm`.

1. Open the PDF document you want to add the margin to in Preview.app
2. Go to *File -> Print*
3. Go to *Paper size -> Manage Custom Sizes...*
4. Add a custom page size by clicking on the `+` in the lower left.
5. Fill in the following values:

   - Width: 310 mm, which is 210 + 100, i.e. the width + the desired margin
   - Height: 297 mm
   - Top margin: 0 mm
   - Bottom margin: 0 mm
   - Left margin: 0 mm
   - Right margin: 100 mm
     [image]
6. Press OK, and make sure the newly create size is selected under *Paper size*
7. Now, in the *Preview* section (you might have to press *Show Details* if you don't see this part) select *Scale to Fit: -> Fill Entire Page*

[image]

8. Now you're almost ready: press *PDF -> Open in Preview* to see the end result and save it.
   [image]

Here's the result I get from an A4 document to which I added a margin of 100 mm on the right:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! The trick using Preview works very well. Changed the width to "original+additional" and the right margin to "additional", it increased the margin without moving the content of the PDF. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, but try pdf-xchanger next time.

Comment: @StackUser2949052 feel free to create a new answer showing how this would be done in pdf-xchanger.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a margin, border, gutter, etc. can easily be accomplished using the professional pdf sofware **PDF-XChange Editor** by [Tracker Software](https://www.tracker-software.com/).

There, use the resize feature in two steps:

1. Resize to something like 110 % without(!) scaling, then
2. Resize (again) to 100 % with scaling enabled.

This can be applied to 1000s of pages. If you have special requirements towards changing the frame sizes (boxes), then this answer might or might not work. PDF-XChange Editor allows also to shift pages left, right, odd, even, etc. in case you need to optimize further.

PS. The not so easy part is to memorize the two-steps. It is not intuitive per se. Additionally, several "Online PDF-Editors" have the feature, but you most likely need a plan for >> 200 pp. etc. and you have limited control over this feature. Finally, Acrobat Pro most likely has to be used in the same way as mentioned above. There is not "add margin" feature in Acrobat Pro.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF page definition can be a number of boundary boxes /Mediabox /Trimbox /Bleedbox, however for viewers there are only 2 of relevance the primary one is /Cropbox and the fall back is /Mediabox so often a PDF file only has a /Mediabox per page and it is used as the /Cropbox

This file has both set to default as "Letter" size 612/72" x 792/72"

[image]

So **to widen the page by 100 mm we simply need to add 283.465 units to both**, HOWEVER when you modify a PDF it will destroy the internal relative addressing, usually corrupting the file. Hence a GUI editor is often the simplest and there are many PDF "croppers" that can alter page shape.

One other method is to "reprint" say via Ghostscript or other re-builders of PDF but that would also alter the internals in other ways, so **ideally we just need a line editor** to systematically change the crop and or media box, keeping all other elements relative without changes.

For cross platform usage Coherent cpdf (free for personal use) is a good option, as it has query and alter /Media and /Crop boxes. Here is the extract from the command line manual.

[image]

Alternative open source for commercial use would possibly be qpdf but that is likely to alter pages in other ways (depending on complexity of contents).